# oprofile binary build error - (liberty library not found)

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, oprofile

After download the oprofile source code on my host ( Ubuntu 15.04 ),
for some reasons, I need to build the binary my own.

I enter the following command to build the binary

```
./configure && make && make install
```

And got the error message

```
configure: error: liberty library not found
```

By searching around the fix to this error, I found a package needs to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-dev
```

However, the same error still appears even thought the package has been installed successfully.

Is there anything I can check with?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the answer.

Please follow the link:

[Configuration error: Iberty library not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160517/configuration-error-iberty-library-not-found)

This answers my question.